# Reset windows resolution blind

Tags: resolution

I set my windows 10 pc 20 pixels over 1080p and the monitor won't accept the input. I now need to revert back to the previous / a lower resolution without being able to see anything..  Don't tell me to interrupt the boot and go into safe mode because that no longer works with (at least mine,  and a few others versions of) windows 10.

Comment: Can you reach your computer via RDP. Are you already logged in the PC? I can think of a way if you can log in, it might require sound so you can hear the narrator speak. Other options would be changing monitors or monitor cable type.

Comment: I believe there is a "Low-Resolution Display Mode" option if you can get to windows recovery options. From there you go to Advanced Repair Option, Troubleshoot, Advanced Options, Windows Startup Settings and choose low res mode

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar issue, the combination that worked for me is: wait about three to five minutes to let your computer settle down from any boot activities.

Do the following exactly:

Right click the mouse.
Press Up on the keyboard twice.
Press Enter.
Press Tab three times.
Press the Space Bar.
Type the number 8.
Press Tab.
Press Enter.
This has forced Windows to switch to the 800x600 Screen Resolution.

Comment: How would you reset the refresh rate